# Whether jQuery can according to article words, automatically add a toggle function?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have many articles. Article structure as follows

```
<p> ___some word___ </p>
<p> ___some word___ </p>
<p> ___some word___ </p>
<p> ___some word___ </p>
...
```

Whether jQuery can according to article words, automatically add a toggle function?
I need: show first 100 words and toggle the rests OR show the first 3 `<p></p>` and toggle the rests.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('p:contains("some word")').toggle(function(){
  //do something
});
```

More info on the :contains selector at http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/